# How to include using Smartwatches in an app written with Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

My company recently came up with an idea to include using smartwatches with the app I wrote using codename one.

Is this possible? If yes, which libraries do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are evaluating the possibility of smartwatch support, this depends on customer demand.

We currently have a major enterprise prospect that has expressed interest in this but hasn't signed up. If your company is serious about this please contact us directly.

Assuming we don't go that route or you need something immediately this depends on your supported platform, you would need to use native interfaces for most functionality. In Android notifications (which we support) should work for Android wear. In iOS we are transitioning to the new xcode 7.x which should support smartwatches too but I'm not sure what would need doing.

Comment: I already expected something like this. Dont expect Mit Company to message you, I am a solo developer